# How to populate dropdown from database laravel 5.x

Tags: html, laravel, view, eloquent, dropdown

Controller side:

```
$regs = Model::all('id','name');

return view('aview',compact('regs'));
```

View side:

```
{{ Form::select('id', $regs) }}
```

The dropdown gets rendered and populated but displays `JSON objects` such as `{"id:1","name: Aname"}` instead of displaying Aname and setting the post value to 1

Comment: Please explain your question, what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

In your controller

```
$regs = Model::pluck('name','id');
```

Keep your view same

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can populate like this:

```
{!! Form::select('id', $regs->lists('name', 'id'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: the lists function has been deprecated, renamed to pluck, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`Form::select` accepts four parameters:

`public function select($name, $list = [], $selected = null, $options = []);`

1. The name of the html field
2. the list of options
3. the selected value
4. an array of html attributes

You can generate the list by using

```
$regs = Model::all('id','name');
$plucked = $regs->pluck('name', 'id');
// $plcuked = ['id1' => 'name1', 'id2' => 'name2' ...]
```

And the blade code should look like this

`{{ Form::select('name', $plucked, null, ['class' => 'form-control']); }}`

Answer (score 0):

I maybe making this problem a bit complicated but I think its worth using the plugin.

You can take the use of very popular plugin - [Select2](https://select2.github.io/). This plugin of jQuery helps you to fetch data from server and populate the fetched data into our dropdown in minutes. Your code goes like this.

```
// Code in your Controller Method
$regs = Model::all();
$data = [];
foreach($regs as $reg) {
      $data[] = [
            'id' => $reg->id,
            'text' => $reg->name
      ];
}
return json_encode(['items' => $data]);


// Code in your desired View
<select id="select_items"></select>


// Code in js
$('#select_items').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/example/api', // <--------- Route to your controller method
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    }
  }
});
```

You can also integrate search options using this plugins as it helps you to fetch results based on your search keywords (for more see [Select2 Examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)). Hope this helps you to solve your problem.